# Always get the same position of readmore link in dynamic content div

Tags: html, css

I got a couple of divs that load content in them, but every content is different, and the read more link at the bottom is pushed along with the content.

How can I get the link to stick to the bottom of the div?

Example:

[image]

The html code of one box:

```
<div class="vertical-item gallery-extended-item with_background text-center" style="height: 330px;">
    <div class="item-media">
        <div class="media-links">
            <a class="abs-link" title="" href="nieuwsbericht-5.html"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
        <h3 class="item-title">
            <a href="nieuwsbericht-5.html">Project test</a>
        </h3>
        <span class="categories-links">
            <a rel="category" href="#" class="theme_button small_button color1">Nieuws</a>
        </span>
        <br>
        <p>Project&nbsp;test opgeleverd - februari 2016</p>
        <p>
            <a href="nieuwsbericht-5.html">Lees verder</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which link ('Nieuws' or 'Lees verder')? And where should it be placed?

Comment: Lees verder, nieuws is not a link. And to the bottom. If I know how to stick it to the bottom I can always position it how I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `absolute` position on the link, he will stay at the same place every time, no matter how long the text above is.

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/8y7aazuc/)

```
.bottom { position: absolute; bottom : 100px; left: 0; right: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid it would break responsiveness but luckily it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try `position:absolute`, along with `bottom`, this will place the element from bottom 20px up.

Below is the updated code `<a class="sbottom" href="nieuwsbericht-5.html">Lees verder</a>`.

```css
.sbottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-item gallery-extended-item with_background text-center" style="height: 330px;">
  <div class="item-media">
    <div class="media-links">
      <a class="abs-link" title="" href="nieuwsbericht-5.html"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-content">
    <h3 class="item-title">
            <a href="nieuwsbericht-5.html">Project test</a>
        </h3>
    <span class="categories-links">
            <a rel="category" href="#" class="theme_button small_button color1">Nieuws</a>
        </span>
    <br>
    <p>Project&nbsp;test opgeleverd - februari 2016</p>
    <p>
      <a class="sbottom" href="nieuwsbericht-5.html">Lees verder</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```